# Springboot Interservices communication Exception handling

Tags: rest, spring-boot, exception

I have a micro-service A which is calling another service B. I am trying to handle the error message using `@ExceptionHandler`.

**I want to propagate the error message received from B to the service A.** But in the rest call response it gives the HttpStatus Code but no body(null). Below is a snapshot:

[image: Exception snapshot]

The response from service B in postman is given below. I want to get the same error response message in my Service A.

[image: Postman response]

Following is my code:

RestServiceCall.java

```
public List<AccessResponse>  daxObjectAccessibilitycall(AccessDataObject requestEntity) {
        ResponseEntity<AccessResponse[]> responseEntity = restTemplate.postForEntity(getFullPathService(), requestEntity, AccessResponse[].class);
        if (responseEntity == null) {
            return Collections.emptyList();
        }

        AccessResponse[] accessResponse = responseEntity.getBody();
        return Arrays.asList(accessResponse);
    }
```

During error handling it throws an exception which is handled in this code:

```
public boolean myFoo(MyDto){
.
.
.

        try {
            myObjectAccessibilitycall = serviceCall.objectAccessibilitycall(accessDataObj);
        } catch (RestClientException e) {
            logger.error("Error while getting response from Accessibility", e);
            throw new myException("Error: ", e);
        }

        if (!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(myObjectAccessibilitycall )) {
            for (AccessResponse accessResponse : myObjectAccessibilitycall ) {
                accessFlag = accessResponse.isResponseMsg();
            }
        }
        return accessFlag;
    }
```

Appreciate any help on this.
Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Two options are there 
1. Use @ControllerAdvice to handle exception. Below we are handling IllegalArgumentException and IllegalStateException exception. Like you need to handle HttpClientErrorException

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class RestResponseEntityExceptionHandler 
  extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(value 
      = { IllegalArgumentException.class, IllegalStateException.class })
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleConflict(
      RuntimeException ex, WebRequest request) {
        String bodyOfResponse = "This should be application specific";
        return handleExceptionInternal(ex, bodyOfResponse, 
          new HttpHeaders(), HttpStatus.CONFLICT, request);
    }
}
```

Option 2. You can catch RestClientResponseException

```
<T> ResponseEntity consumeWebService(String url, Class<T> responseType) {  
    try {
        return restTemplate.getForEntity(url, responseType);
    } catch (RestClientResponseException e) {
        return ResponseEntity
            .status(e.getRawStatusCode())
            .body(e.getResponseBodyAsString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Option 2 suits my use case, in e.getResponseBodyAsString its giving a null value